# Are Fields subsets of Integral Domains or is it the other way round?

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question

I recently came across a Theorem that mentioned "Every field is an integral domain." This makes me think that if F is any field and D is any integral domain, then $F \subseteq D$. But then I also encountered a line in an abstract algebra text that mentioned "every integral domain can be regarded as being contained in a certain field" which makes me think that $D \subseteq F$. **How are these two propositions not contradictory? Are Fields subsets of Integral Domains or is it the other way round?**

Comment: Is $F=\mathbb R$ contained in $D=\mathbb Q$?

Comment: I don't think that $\Bbb Q\subseteq \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $\mathbb Q$ is a field and an integral domain; $\mathbb Z$ is an integral domain. The collection of all fields is a subcollection of all integral domains, but a particular integral domain can be regarded as being contained in its field of fractions.   $\mathbb Z\subset \mathbb Q$

Comment: "This makes me think that if F is any field and D is any integral domain, then $F \subseteq D$."  That's quite a statement... for *any* field and *any* integral domain, the field is a subset of the integral domain?  That's definitely not true, e.g., $\mathbb{C}$ is not a subset of $\mathbb{Z}$...

Comment: "Every field is an integral domain" just means that if $F$ is a field, then $F$ is also an integral domain.

Comment: In fact, for every field $F$ you have an integral domain (that is not a field) that contains it, namely the polynomial ring $F[x]$, and for every integral domain there is a field that contains it, namely the ring of fractions.  That's not contradictory, it just means you get infinite nested sets of alternating fields and integral domains. $F \subsetneq F[x] \subsetneq F(x) \subsetneq F(x)[y] \subsetneq F(x)(y)$...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you have interpreted them, the two statements are not contradictory: the two together imply $D=F$.

However, you have interpreted the first statement incorrectly.

"Every field is an integral domain" means that the *set* of fields is a subset of the *set* of integral domains, not that any particular field is a subset of any particular integral domain.

Your interpretation of the second statement is (mostly) correct though. The quibble is that the field $F$ depends on the integral domain $D$ in question, and is not arbitrary. This means: **Integral domains are subsets of fields, not (necessarily) the other way around.**

Comment: +1, (Except that I don't think that the class of all fields is a set)

Answer (score 1):

(There can be issues when you talk about sets which might be too large.)

But, every field is an integral domain.  Not conversley, as for instance, $\Bbb Z$ (after which integral domains are named).

For the second statement, given an integral domain, we could, for instance, consider its field of fractions, which would contain it as a subdomain.  There might also be other fields containing a given integral domain, and often are.

Comment: and every subdomain of an integral domain must again be an integral domain. Am I right?

Comment: A subring of an integral domain will be an integral domain if you require  it to be _unital_.